# Undefined method, avatar and name for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, undefined, null, avatar

undefined method `avatar?' for nil:NilClass
undefined method`name' for nil:NilClass

Hi, I'm receiving the following errors in my partial. The reason I listed both is because after commenting out the line causing the first error message, I get the second error which leads me to believe the problem isn't with "avatar" or "name" specifically, but with something else,though I don't know what. In rails console, I'm able to call user and name on a comment. I also seeded the database using Faker if that matters.  Here's the partial.

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: 'media', id: "comment-#{comment.id}" do %>
  <%= link_to '#', class: 'pull-left' do %>
    <%= image_tag(comment.user.avatar.small.url) if comment.user.avatar?  %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="media-body">
    <small>
      <%= comment.user.name %> commented <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
      <% if policy(comment).destroy? %>
        | <%= link_to "Delete", [@topic, @post, comment], method: :delete %>
      <% end %>
    </small>
    <p><%= comment.body %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Also, please see the render.

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <% if policy(Comment.new).create? %>
      <h4>Leave a comment</h4>
      <br/>
      <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post, comment: @comment } %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The below are my user model and comments_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def update
    if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "User information updated"
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path(current_user)
    else
      render "devise/registrations/edit"
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :avatar)
  end
end
```

Comments_controller

```
  def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = @topic.posts.find(params[:post_id])
    @comments = @post.comments

    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.post = @post
    @new_comment = Comment.new

    authorize @comment
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to [@topic, @post], notice: "Comment was submitted successfully."
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error submitting the comment. Please try again."
    end
  end
```

I've already reset the database, but to no avail. Stuck as to what the issue is. Thanks for your help.

Please see below for my User and Comment models.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

  default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }

  validates :body, length: { minimum: 5 }, presence: true

  after_create :send_favorite_emails

  private

  def send_favorite_emails
    self.post.favorites.each do |favorite|
      if favorite.user_id != self.user_id && favorite.user.email_favorites?
        FavoriteMailer.new_comment(favorite.user, self.post, self).deliver
      end
    end
  end
end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  def role?(base_role)
    role == base_role.to_s
  end

  def favorited(post)
    self.favorites.where(post_id: post.id).first
  end

  def voted(post)
    self.votes.where(post_id: post.id).first
  end

  private
end
```

Comment: `nil:NilClass` errors are typically because you're either calling an undelcared variable *or* the var you're using has `nil` data inside

Comment: Can you show us your `User` and `Comment` models?

Comment: user is not set on comment is what it's saying. Why? Well that's somewhere up stream. Around current_user.comments.build(comment_params) is where I'd be looking.

Comment: Wait, how is `comment` set in your view if you set `@comment` in the controller? Shouldn't you be using `@comment`?

Comment: @RichPeck - I added the comment and user models.  I suspected the issue was with what the method was being called on, but like I wrote up above, in rails console, all the comments have a user_id.  Also, I'm a newbie, so I don't know what else to look for

Comment: Can you please add the comments permitted params? Might be that the problem is that the permitted params in the comment skips the user_id. Try to explicitly add user_id in the permitted values in the comments controller and restart your server and drop create migrate seed then try it once more

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting

> undefined method `foo` for `nil:NilClass`

it's that the thing you're calling your method on is `nil`.

So in your case, you're calling `avatar?` and `name` on *something* nil.

Looking at your code, it's clear `comment.user` is (a) what those methods are called on, and hence (b) what is nil.

Result: your comment has no user. Either enforce all comments (including new/empty/stub ones) to have an user (blank user?), or make your view so that a user is not necessary.

Comment: I added the comment and user models.  I suspected the issue was with what the method was being called on, but like I wrote up above, in rails console, all the comments have a user_id.  Also, I'm a newbie, so I don't know what else to look for

Comment: @user3465296 What I'd do in your situation would be to use [pry](http://pryrepl.org/) (gem `pry-rails`) and insert a `<% binding.pry %>` in your view just before the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was discovered.  In the partial render

```
comment: @comment
```

should be

```
comment: comment
```